# In windows 7, is it possible to extend a logical partition using space, freed up from shrinking the windows(primary) partition? If yes, how?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Please take a look at the snapshot of my current partitions -

[image: screenshot: Disk Management]

I want to shrink volume C to a total size of 80 GB or so and use the remaining free space to extend the volume D. Is there a safe way to do so without the need of formatting any volume or losing any files on any volume? In my search I found that free space must be contiguous to the volume that's been extended. So in my case the free space will be adjacent and on the left of volume D, Can I then merge this in volume D? 
In addition to that, can I, in any way shrink my volume F and merge this freed space in volume D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is very possible. However, in order to extend C>D you will need to use a 3rd party tool such as EASEUS Partition Tool. It is very simple. Shrink the partition first and then use the tool to merge them.

http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Here are more detailed instructions

http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/merge-partition.htm

Comment: +1 IMO the best freeware. But remember it will just merge the partition to just its right side one.

Comment: @avirk It can also MOVE partitions, so you can have the free space on the right side of the partition to extend.

Comment: So if I use any of the third party tool(or EaseUS) to move a partition, there won't be any risk of data loss? Because I have nothing where I can backup 140 GB of data.

Comment: @Abhishek: There will *always* be some amount of risk involved with operations such as these. If you cannot even borrow a USB HDD from someone temporarily to take a backup, either accept the risk and proceed, else hold off on doing this till you can ensure the safety of your data.

Comment: It is possible to use Minitools as well.